# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{sech} x \, \mathrm{d}x =\pi\;$?

Tags: calculus, pi, hyperbolic-functions

According to Desmos,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{sech} x \, \mathrm{d}x = 3.14159265359$$

Why is $\pi$ here in this definite integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- That's magic of [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), a bridge (other than Jacobi elliptic functions) relates trigonometric to hyperbolic functions:

\begin{align}
  \operatorname{gd} x &= \int_0^x \operatorname{sech} t \, dt \\
  &= \tan^{-1} \sinh x \\
  \operatorname{gd}^{-1} t &= \int_0^t \operatorname{sec} x \, dx \\
  &= \tanh^{-1} \sin t \\
\end{align}

- Further *coincidence*:

\begin{align}
  \operatorname{gd} x &= \tan^{-1} \sinh x \\
  &= \sin^{-1} \tanh x \\
  \operatorname{gd}^{-1} t &= \tanh^{-1} \sin t \\
  &= \sinh^{-1} \tan t
\end{align}

- Domain for $t$ is always $\left( -\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\operatorname{sech}(x) = \frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}.$ In that case:

$$I= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sech}(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1} dx.$$

For the later, $u=e^x \implies du=e^xdx$,

$$I = 2\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{1}{u^2+1} du = 2 \left(\lim_{u \to \infty} \arctan(u)  - 0 \right) = \pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just as you do it with trigonometric functions, in the case of hyperbolic functions, you can use the corresponding tangent half-angle substitution
$$x=2 \tanh ^{-1}(t)\implies dx=\frac{2}{1-t^2}\,dt$$
$$I=\int \text{sech}(x)\,dx=\int\frac{2}{t^2+1}\,dt=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$ Similarly
$$J=\int \text{csch}(x)\,dx=\log \left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$